# must Visual Studio 2013 project dependencies be setup manually?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build

I have just combined several Visual Studio projects into a single solution and removed and recreated all the references from dependent projects to upstream projects.

Unfortunately `Project > Project Dependencies` are all blank. This [stackoverflow dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053356/project-build-order-in-visual-studio-2010) appears to suggest that the dependencies should be automatic and based upon the references, however, this automation is not happening in my solution.

The build order that is visible in `Project > Project Build Order` appears to be correct. Unfortunately a solution build will fail even though the *starting order* is correct. The failure can be attributed to upstream project builds failing to complete soon enough for downstream dependent projects. This might be partly due to the fact that builds start almost concurrently and there is no waiting for the completion of upstream projects. Given that the starts are concurrent, the build order seems to offer no practical benefit.

While the programmer can manually setup values in `Project > Dependencies` I want to avoid manual processes as much as possible if there is a solution.

This system is Visual Studio 2013 Express with Update 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is at this link. [A stackoverflow answer related to the build order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427439/visual-studio-2013-solution-building-not-in-build-order). Apparently the number of concurrent builds can be decreased but if you don't want to do that, the answer at the link says that the programmer has to manually set the dependencies.